# Que un script realize un comando en otras maquinas de manera remota

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh

Estoy intentando realizar un script para sacar las salidas del compando lscpu en distintas maquinas que puedo alcanzar de manera remota mediante el comando sshpass, el bucle while va recorriendo una lista de maquinas por su direccion ip y ejecutando el comando. El problema es que si ejecuto el lscpu con sshpass solo me lo hace en la primera maquina y luego no vuelve a pasar por ese if y no me lo ejecuta en los demas.
Abajo dejo el codigo no os fijeis en las variables que pongo u otras cosas ya que son para comprobaciones secundarias y puedo decir que no tienen nada que ver.

El fallo tiene que estar en algo relacionado con el comando sshpass pues si lo comento me recorre el if todas las veces, sin embargo si no lo comento me ejecuta el lscpu en la primera maquina que encuentra y luego se sale del programa.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
#!/bin/bash

fichero_hosts="/etc/hosts"

function recorrerHosts {
        string_recorrer=$1
        tres_iniciales=${string_recorrer:0:3}
        sufijo_final=${string_recorrer: -1}
        while IFS= read -r line
        do
                ip_host=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f 1)
                name_host=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f 2)
                if [[ ${ip_host:0:2} =~ $re ]] ; then
                        if [[ ${name_host:0:3} == $tres_iniciales ]] && [[ ${name_host: -1} == $sufijo_final ]] ; then
                                contador=$(($contador+1))
                                echo "$contador - $line"
                                sshpass -p root ssh root@$ip_host lscpu
                                echo "me coloque aqui dentro"
                        fi
                fi
        done < $fichero_hosts
        contador=0
}

recorrerHosts s56n
```

Comment: fíjate que estás haciendo `sshpass ... lscpu > fichero`. Esto truncará el fichero en cada iteración. Usa `>>` para ir añadiendo contenido.

Comment: perdona acabo de editar la pregunta que eso de enviarlo al fichero solo era para hacer pruebas, quiero q me lo saque por pantalla y solo me saca el primero de todos

Comment: ¿has validado si lees el fichero correctamente? Prueba con un "echo" en lugar de "sshpass" cada vez.

Comment: si ,lo lee entero, de echo si en vez de utilizar un comando como lscpu o ls, utilizo un reboot lo hace bien y me reinicia todas las maquinas

Comment: no es mas sencillo hacer `while read ip_host name_host resto; do blah blah; done < $fichero_post`? (no relacionado a la pregunta en si, en todo caso)